# HTML font family display delayed after displaying default font family

Tags: html, css, fonts

I am having an issue with my web page:

I am using google's font "Source Sans Pro" for my website's text. 
This is how my html looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Document</title>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
    body {
        font-family: "Source Sans Pro";
        font-size: 45px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>Simply The Best </p>
</body>
</html>
```

When I display the page, I found the page flash to display the text as "Times New Roman" or some web browser default font family, then change the font to google font. No matter I import in css, or link in my header, it has same efforts.

Can any one help to explain to me the reason and how should I solve it? Is it because the loading delay of //fonts.googleapis.com/css?

Thanks for help in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro" rel="stylesheet">
```

instead of your:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

as in your code it has `font-display: swap;` and this is the reason why you are having that flash.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using import to style the fonts and I had 3 or 4 seconds delay and I deleted `&display=swap` and it's working. I am not sure if its the right approach

It was

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100;0,400;1,100&display=swap');
```

Changed to

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100;0,400;1,100');
```